¿Cómo crear un data frame con los valores que asigna pheatmap?
Estoy utilizando la función pheatmap en R para generar un mapa de calor. Me gustaría crear un data frame con los valores que aporta pheatmap en la escala de color.
Es decir, a partir de este hm de ejemplo
set.seed(8)
m <- matrix(rnorm(36), 6, 6)
colnames(m) <- paste("Col", 1:6)
rownames(m) <- paste("Row", 1:6)
hm <- as.data.frame(m)

pheatmap(as.matrix(hm), 
         scale="row",
         clustering_method = "complete", 
         cluster_rows = F , 
         cluster_cols = F, gaps_col = 3,
         clustering_distance_rows = "correlation",
         show_rownames = F,display_numbers = T,
         cellheight = NA, cellwidth = NA,
         color=colorRampPalette(c("royalblue1", "white", "firebrick2"))(100),
         fontsize_row = 10, angle_col = 0, fontsize_for_colnames = 10,
         filename = "hm.pdf")


dput(df)

structure(list(`Col 1` = c(-0.0845860713710238, 0.840400125597476, 
-0.463482772187991, -0.550835004480379, 0.736040432105293, -0.107881401506818
), `Col 2` = c(-0.17028914982177, -1.08833171186954, -3.01105167576798, 
-0.593174332801249, -0.759793796302071, 0.292049863660693), `Col 3` = c(0.421398594579087, 
-1.29448908100089, 0.069285088863449, -0.813038477272046, 1.51085307235785, 
-0.271608879959897), `Col 4` = c(1.55825392862137, -0.237349870104542, 
1.28312288225294, -0.00948963582193302, -0.400082781659235, 0.0219856238212091
), `Col 5` = c(1.74276738119779, -1.10717415930603, -1.06048948248981, 
1.95116131935762, 0.602706742607104, -2.02060948083538), `Col 6` = c(1.50667554287554, 
0.963711089169582, -1.55389141221093, -0.773642378723716, 1.26077795552575, 
0.428455778881058)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Row 1", 
"Row 2", "Row 3", "Row 4", "Row 5", "Row 6"))

¿Cómo puedo extraer dichos valores?

Podrías copiar la estructura de hm a tu pregunta, básicamente la salida de dput(hm)

Es bastante complicado extraer los datos directamente del objeto pheatmap al menos para este tipo de gráfico, sin embargo, revisando el código fuente, se puede ver que en función de los parámetros se termina invocando a esta función
scale_rows = function(x){
  m = apply(x, 1, mean, na.rm = T)
  s = apply(x, 1, sd, na.rm = T)
  return((x - m) / s)
}

En tu caso el parámetro scale="row" escala por fila cada valor menos la media dividido la desviación estándar. Esta función puedes aplicarla a tu matriz:
scale_rows(hm)

           Col 1      Col 2       Col 3       Col 4      Col 5      Col 6
Row 1 -1.0445144 -1.1424959 -0.46603903  0.83368969  1.0446378  0.7747218
Row 2  1.1427011 -0.7557310 -0.95864971  0.08188219 -0.7742774  1.2640749
Row 3  0.2224662 -1.5163703  0.58610548  1.41460731 -0.1850192 -0.5217894
Row 4 -0.3955894 -0.4355315 -0.64294697  0.11510507  1.9647443 -0.6057815
Row 5  0.2709759 -1.3882598  1.13042724 -0.98925483  0.1230771  0.8530345
Row 6  0.1887421  0.6370190  0.00522243  0.33430805 -1.9552058  0.7899143


Para extraer las etiquetas del gráfico, procede de la siguiente manera:
1 - Realiza el gráfico y guárdalo con cualquier nombre, en este caso, yo lo guardo con el nombre out
out <- pheatmap(as.matrix(hm), 
                scale="row",
                clustering_method = "complete", 
                cluster_rows = F , 
                cluster_cols = F, gaps_col = 3,
                clustering_distance_rows = "correlation",
                show_rownames = F,display_numbers = T,
                cellheight = NA, cellwidth = NA,
                color=colorRampPalette(c("royalblue1", "white", "firebrick2"))(100),
                fontsize_row = 10, angle_col = 0, fontsize_for_colnames = 10 ,
                filename = "hm.pdf")  # Este es exactamente tu código

2 - out es una lista que contiene mucha información, solo basta navegar dentro de ella para ubicar los elementos de etiqueta, se convierten a tipo numérico y luego se da formato de matriz con igual dimensión que hm:
out$gtable$grobs[[1]]$children[[2]]$label |>
  as.numeric() |>
  matrix(ncol = ncol(hm), dimnames = list(rownames(hm), colnames(hm)))
      Col 1 Col 2 Col 3 Col 4 Col 5 Col 6
Row 1 -1.04 -1.14 -0.47  0.83  1.04  0.77
Row 2  1.14 -0.76 -0.96  0.08 -0.77  1.26
Row 3  0.22 -1.52  0.59  1.41 -0.19 -0.52
Row 4 -0.40 -0.44 -0.64  0.12  1.96 -0.61
Row 5  0.27 -1.39  1.13 -0.99  0.12  0.85
Row 6  0.19  0.64  0.01  0.33 -1.96  0.79

Alternativa a la solución de @Patricio Moracho es usar la función scale() para estandarizar/tipificar las variables, t() para transponer el resultado, finalmente se convierte a data.frame:
> t(scale(t(hm))) |> as.data.frame()
           Col 1      Col 2       Col 3       Col 4      Col 5      Col 6
Row 1 -1.0445144 -1.1424959 -0.46603903  0.83368969  1.0446378  0.7747218
Row 2  1.1427011 -0.7557310 -0.95864971  0.08188219 -0.7742774  1.2640749
Row 3  0.2224662 -1.5163703  0.58610548  1.41460731 -0.1850192 -0.5217894
Row 4 -0.3955894 -0.4355315 -0.64294697  0.11510507  1.9647443 -0.6057815
Row 5  0.2709759 -1.3882598  1.13042724 -0.98925483  0.1230771  0.8530345
Row 6  0.1887421  0.6370190  0.00522243  0.33430805 -1.9552058  0.7899143

